# Unable to display custom-made (running time) widget in grid (codes from QtDesigner)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am not too sure how to display a custom-made widget into the grid that I have set up using QtDesigner, and will appreciate if you could see what is wrong with setting up my codes in this manner, and also explain to me why I can't do that.

I have tried to add the widget from the function I have created to import my widget, but it does not work as well. Doing the following code below also did not work. I am not sure how to add widgets to my grid and set my grid as the parent grid, while setting the new widget as the child widget.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from SelectDateTimeFinal import Ui_SelectDateTime
from CurrentDateAndDigitalClock import Ui_widget_currentDate_digitalClock

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def openCurrentDateAndDigitalClock(self):
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Ui = Ui_widget_currentDate_digitalClock()
        self.Ui.setupUi(self.widget)
#NEED HEP HERE

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(950, 565)
        MainWindow.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.pushButton_Store3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_Store3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 400, 321, 29))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Goudy Old Style")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_Store3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_Store3.setObjectName("pushButton_Store3")

        self.pushButton_Store2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_Store2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 330, 331, 29))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Goudy Old Style")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_Store2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_Store2.setObjectName("pushButton_Store2")

        self.pushButton_Store1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_Store1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 330, 321, 29))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Goudy Old Style")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_Store1.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_Store1.setObjectName("pushButton_Store1")

        self.pushButton_Store4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_Store4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 400, 331, 29))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Goudy Old Style")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_Store4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_Store4.setObjectName("pushButton_Store4")

        self.pushButton_Reset = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_Reset.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 271, 29))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Goudy Old Style")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_Reset.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_Reset.setObjectName("pushButton_Reset")

        self.pushButton_SetDateTime = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_SetDateTime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 271, 29))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Goudy Old Style")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_SetDateTime.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_SetDateTime.setObjectName("pushButton_SetDateTime")

        self.pushButton_SetDateTime.clicked.connect(self.openSelectDateTimeWindow)

        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 20, 281, 101))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout_SelectedDateTime = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout_SelectedDateTime.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_SelectedDateTime.setObjectName("gridLayout_SelectedDateTime")

        self.label_SelectedDateTime = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.label_SelectedDateTime.setText("")
        self.label_SelectedDateTime.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_SelectedDateTime.setObjectName("label_SelectedDateTime")
        self.gridLayout_SelectedDateTime.addWidget(self.label_SelectedDateTime, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.gridLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(640, 20, 291, 101))
        self.gridLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget_2")

        self.gridLayout_CurrentDateTime = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.gridLayout_CurrentDateTime.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_CurrentDateTime.setObjectName("gridLayout_CurrentDateTime")
        self.gridLayout_CurrentDateTime.addChildWidget(self.openCurrentDateAndDigitalClock)
# NEED HELP HERE

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Canteen System"))
        self.pushButton_Store3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_Store2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_Store1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_Store4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_Reset.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Reset to Current Date and Time"))
        self.pushButton_SetDateTime.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Set Date and Time"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(Ui_widget_currentDate_digitalClock.showDate)
    timer.timeout.connect(Ui_widget_currentDate_digitalClock.showTime)
    timer.start(100)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want my widget (which is a running date and time clock) to appear in the grid, as I will use that widget in other windows that I will create and would like to know how to apply it to other windows. I tried to run the following code but an error `exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)` keeps appearing.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure without seeing the code for `Ui_widget_currentDat_digitalClock`, but I suspect that this

```
timer.timeout.connect(Ui_widget_currentDate_digitalClock.showDate)
timer.timeout.connect(Ui_widget_currentDate_digitalClock.showTime)
```

should be something like

```
timer.timeout.connect(ui.Ui.showDate)
timer.timeout.connect(ui.Ui.showTime)
```

And in `Ui_MainWindow.setupUi`, this line

```
self.gridLayout_CurrentDateTime.addChildWidget(self.openCurrentDateAndDigitalClock)
```

should be something like

```
self.openCurrentDateAndDigitalClock()    # this sets up self.widget 
self.gridLayout_CurrentDateTime.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The output generated by pyuic should never be used as a base for your code. In fact, it should be just left alone, mostly because you might need to change your GUI at some point, making it very hard to integrate the new code with the existing one you edited until then.

As explained in the [PyQt documentation](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code), you should import that code instead and use it as a starting point for your application, from where you create the actual class of your windows and widgets and add the required connections and program logic.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget
from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
from CurrentDateAndDigitalClock import Ui_widget_currentDate_digitalClock

class DigitalClock(QWidget, Ui_widget_currentDate_digitalClock):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DigitalClock, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.digitalClock = DigitalClock()
        self.gridLayout_CurrentDateTime.addWidget(self.digitalClock)

        self.pushButton_SetDateTime.clicked.connect(self.openSelectDateTimeWindow)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Also, you never should use `addChildWidget`, which is an internal function used by QLayout subclasses. Use the specific layout's `addWidget` method instead.

Please note that since you've not shared the code you used for your custom widget, I've not added the timer connection; I'm afraid that there could be some problem since you've connected it to the *class* methods `showDate` and `showTime`, while connection that require some level of GUI interaction (including automatically updating some text with a timer) should be done using the class *instance* methods.